# Probability Question - Bear Catching Fish

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, problem-solving

A bear wants  to catch $3$ fish from a river. When he has caught $3$ fish, he'll leave. When a fish comes, there is a $50\%$ chance he'll catch it. What's the probability that the $5^{th}$ fish will not be caught?

My attempt at a solution is below and in the answers section, could someone please verify that the logic and calculation checks out.

My solution:

The probability that the 5th fish will not be caught is equal to the probability that the bear catches 3 fish before he gets to the 5th fish, plus the probability that the bear doesn't catch 3 fish before he gets to the 5th fish, and he then doesn't catch the 5th fish.

P(Bear catches 3 fish before getting to fish 5) = P(Bear catches first 3 fish) + P(Bear catches 3 of first 4 fish)

Furthermore, if 1 represents that a fish has been caught, and 0 represents that a fish hasn't been caught, then we get 111 as the sequence that corresponds to the bear catching the first 3 fish, where the first fish is represented by the leftmost 1, and the last fish is represented by rightmost 1.

Then,

P(Bear catches first 3 fish) = (1/2)^3 = 1/8

For P(Bear catches 3 of first 4 fish), our sequences are as follows: 1101, 1011, and 0111. We exclude 1110, as the bear will not try to catch the 4th fish in this case, because it has already caught 3 fish.

Then,

P(Bear catches 3 of first 4 fish) = 3(1/2)^4 = 3/16

Thus,

P(Bear catches 3 fish before getting to fish 5) = P(Bear catches first 3 fish) + P(Bear catches 3 of first 4 fish) = 1/8 + 3/16 = 5/16

And,

P(Bear doesn't catch 3 fish before he gets to the 5th fish, and he then doesn't catch the 5th fish) = (1-P(Bear catches 3 fish before getting to fish 5))*P(Bear doesn't catch fish 5) = (1 - 5/16)(1/2) = 11/32

Finally,

P(5th Fish will not be caught) = P(Bear catches 3 fish before getting to fish 5) + P(Bear doesn't catch 3 fish before he gets to the 5th fish, and he then doesn't catch the 5th fish) = 5/16 + 11/32 = 21/32 = 0.65625

Can someone please verify whether my logic and calculations are indeed correct, and if not, identify my mistake?

Comment: Surely you must have some idea as to what it would take for the 5th fish not to get caught ...

Comment: @EthanBolker Please look at my solution below and let me know if it checks out. Thanks

Comment: @Bram28 Indeed, I do, please look at my solution below and let me know if it checks out.

Answer (score 5):

**My solution:**

The probability that the 5th fish will not be caught is equal to the probability that the bear catches 3 fish before he gets to the 5th fish, plus the probability that the bear doesn't catch 3 fish before he gets to the 5th fish, and he then doesn't catch the 5th fish.

P(Bear catches 3 fish before getting to fish 5) = P(Bear catches first 3 fish) + P(Bear catches 3 of first 4 fish)

Furthermore, if 1 represents that a fish has been caught, and 0 represents that a fish hasn't been caught, then we get 111 as the sequence that corresponds to the bear catching the first 3 fish, where the first fish is represented by the leftmost 1, and the last fish is represented by rightmost 1.

Then,

P(Bear catches first 3 fish) = (1/2)^3 = 1/8

For P(Bear catches 3 of first 4 fish), our sequences are as follows: 1101, 1011, and 0111. We exclude 1110, as the bear will not try to catch the 4th fish in this case, because it has already caught 3 fish.

Then,

P(Bear catches 3 of first 4 fish) = 3(1/2)^4 = 3/16

Thus,

P(Bear catches 3 fish before getting to fish 5) = P(Bear catches first 3 fish) + P(Bear catches 3 of first 4 fish) = 1/8 + 3/16 = 5/16

And,

P(Bear doesn't catch 3 fish before he gets to the 5th fish, and he then doesn't catch the 5th fish) = (1-P(Bear catches 3 fish before getting to fish 5))*P(Bear doesn't catch fish 5) = (1 - 5/16)(1/2) = 11/32

Finally,

P(5th Fish will not be caught) = P(Bear catches 3 fish before getting to fish 5) + P(Bear doesn't catch 3 fish before he gets to the 5th fish, and he then doesn't catch the 5th fish) = 5/16 + 11/32 = 21/32 = 0.65625

Can someone please verify whether my logic and calculations are indeed correct, and if not, identify my mistake?

Comment: Looks OK to me (quick read). I'd draw the binary tree  of possibilities and check the probabilities at the relevant leaves - a visual way to do what you did in words.

Comment: @user495261 Looks OK to me as well ... certainly your approach is correct. Good job! .. and for future posts, do include your attempts like this in your question, so we know you worked on it yourself (no one likes to feel like they do someone else's HW) and so that if there are any issues, we can point to specific problems or provide specific suggestions or pointers.

Comment: @Bram28 Thanks for the feedback and advice. I wasn't sure if it was a good idea to post my attempt in the question portion itself because of how long it was, but I'll definitely do so from now on forth. Not actually a HW problem though, I came across it on the internet, and there was a different answer given there, so I just wanted to verify whether my approach was correct. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: @SMZ Yeah, I figured it wasn't your HW ... you just never want to make it look like it could be your HW and that you haven't tried anything yourself yet, because then it will be downvoted and closed very quickly :)

Comment: P(Bear catches 3 of first 4 fish) = 3(1/2)^4 = 3/16 .... is this correct? shouldn't it be 4 choose 3 which is times 4 not 3.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the bear does not leave, there are $2^5=32$ possible outcomes, which fish five would expect to survive 16. Because the bear leaves after three fish, this will increase the number of ways it can survive for sure. This is the number of ways trimmed from the tree (C = fish caught, S = fish survives, X = bear left):

CCCXX = $2^2$ = 4

SCCCX = $2^1$ = 2

CSCCX = $2^1$ = 2

CCSCX = $2^1$ = 2

4+2+2+2 = 10 ways.

This means 10 of the 32 tree branches the fish survives for sure, and this leaves 32-10 = 22 ways with a 50% chance of survival, therefore the fish would survive 11. This gives 10+11=21 possible ways for the fish to survive.

Thus the probability that fish five survives is 21/32.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but how do you get 4 ways of counting CCCXX?

Comment: Looks like he maybe accounting for how many of the 2^5 cases are not valid. So how many CCC _ _ cases end up with no fish caught? well there are 2^2 cases.

Answer (score 0):

Combinatorial Answer:

- The total number of 5 element sequences is $\vert\Omega\vert=2^5=32$.

Let's enumerate all the right sequences:

- The first 3 fish are caught: $1$ choice for the first 3, and $2^2$ for the remaining 2 so, $4$ sequences.
- The 4th fish is the 3rd being caught: we need to choose 2 fish caught among the first 3 so $\binom{3}{2}=3$, and we have $2$ choices for the last element so $2\times 3 = 6$ sequences.
- 2 fishes are caught among the first 4, and the last one is not caught: we have $\binom{4}{2}=6$ sequences.
- 1 fish is caught among the first 4, and the last one is not caught: we have $\binom{4}{1}=4$ sequences.
- Non of the fishes are caught: $1$ sequence.

So the probability that the 5th fish is not caught is:
$$ P = \frac{4+6+6+4+1}{32}=\frac{21}{32}$$